# Elementor - Control Section when Widget is inserted

Tags: wordpress, elementor

is there any way to control a Section when a Widget is inserted?

I'm creating a widget that needs the section to be without margins and paddings;

So, when inserting it into a section automatically the margins and paddings would be set to 0 and the column layout set to no spacing.

[image]

I didn't find anything talking about it in the official Elementor documentation.